# prove that $Inn(A) \ne Aut(A)$ , A is abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A \ne \{e\}$ be abelian group which is not isomorphic to $Z_2 $.
Prove that $Inn(A) \ne Aut(A) $.

first, I have proved that $Inn(A) = \{id_a\} $.

So, we need to prove that A got a not trivial automorphism.

I consider 2 cases:

1) there exist $x \in A $  such that $x \ ^ 2 \ne e $ , in this case I defined $f : A \to A  $ $f(a) = a $ for $a\in A $  $a\ne x, x\ ^2 $ , and $f(x) = x \ ^ 2 , f(x \ ^ 2) =x $ , f is indeed automorphism.

2) for each $a \in A $ it is true that $a \ ^ 2 = e $. im not sure how to continue from here

Thanks for helping.

Comment: The laws of a group involve an operation that defines an automorphism which is nontrivial most of the time.

Comment: If you have two elements of order $2$, you can interchange them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless $a^2=e$ for all, the map $ x \mapsto x^{-1}$ is a nontrivial automorphism.

If $a^2=e$ for all, then $A$ is a vector space over $\mathbb F_2$ and so has a basis. The map that swaps two elements of that basis is a nontrivial automorphism.

Comment: This argument requires the existence of a basis, which equivalent to the axiom of choice. There may be an argument that avoids that. I think it's unlikely though because one has to deal very large abelian groups, which may not even be finitely generated...

Comment: @lhs You don't need a full basis, just two nonzero elements.

Comment: Shouldn't it be, "unless $a^2=e$ for all $a\in A$"?

Comment: @CamiloArosemena, right, fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. this is exactly what i thought to do, wasn't sure if im right about the existence of a basis .. @lhf